# Redirecting login page to home page when user is logged in using django 2.2

Tags: html, django

I want to redirect users to the homepage when they already logged in and tried to access the login page again. I am using django 2.2. I tried to use user.is_authenticated but it didn't work

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% block chess_page %}
    {% endblock %}

{% else %}
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="../../static/img/chess-logo.jpg" name="logo-pic">
        <h2>Chess</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

chess_page is the homepage I want to redirect to

Comment: But redirecting is not something you can do in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking user.is_authenticated in the template check it in the view that is being used to render the login page, check for request.user.is_authenticated in the login view and redirect to home page based on is_authenticated condition like below:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # redirect to homepage
        # "chess_page" is the name you gave while creating url
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("chess_page"))
    else:
        # render login page
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and could you also tell me what should import in views.py?

Comment: It depends on what you need, In the above function you need to import HttpResponseRedirect, reverse and render.  "from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect" and "from django.shortcuts import render, reverse" are the imports.